# How strong can someone make a Level 1 fighter, in Pathfinder, excluding Polymorph spells that change their body to another creature type?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, optimization

It's a classic trope in fiction, the "not so great" heroic character is going up against a foe they have no business trying to defeat and one (or more) of their allies that are a bit more powerful do a little something here, a little nudge there, and now the would-be hero is performing feats they never would have been able to do on their own.

What, in your estimation, would be the way to go about showing this sort of trope in a game like Pathfinder 1e? Defensive buffs out the wazoo are all well and good, but their low HD is also something to keep in mind, as Con buffs will be less effective. To ensure that the illusion is kept up as well, they'll need to stay as their original race, no True Polymorphing them into a dragon or whatnot.

Comment: Welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! We handle questions that have a definitive answer and ones that can be handled by applying hard earned expertise. This sounds like some kind of optimization question, which is fine, but it is phrased in a way that makes me think you expect some kind of back-and-forth like a forum. Could you add details about what should be maximized about this character? Are you just looking for a list of every buff spell that could be put on a 1st level character? Are you looking for specific immunities?

Comment: You mention polymorph not being acceptable (True Polymorph doesn't exist, but there are similar effects available) but what about other visible benefits, such as Life Bubble and Barkskin? Is there an expected duration that these buffs should have at a minimum, or are the high-powered allies going to follow the would be hero around casting them every time it seems like combat is going to happen? Should this include magic items?

Comment: Also, is this a numerical combat optimization, or are you looking for a Tier optimization, enabling the level 1 no-mag to accomplish non-combat feats and fight a variety of creatures that would (otherwise) cause issues for them?

Comment: You've written that they get help from "one of their allies who is a bit more powerful".  Do you want to apply a limit to the amount of help they can get?  For example no 200,000gp magic items, no fifth-level spells or above, no spending thousands of gold pieces...?

Comment: Also, your question makes it sound like you're looking specifically at the strength stat, but your later text suggests you mean strong in the general combat sense. Further, should we assume that those buffing the 1st level fighter are also 1st level? How many different spellcasters? Any price ceiling on magic items (price being a general gauge of power), or will any magic items do?

Comment: (we're asking these questions because, as-is, your question is asking us to make a list of every buff spell in the game.  that would be a lot of work and it's probably not really what you wanted.)